# How to solve this error "ERROR 102 sql state 420000" which comes up when I try to create this procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, procedure

I am trying to create a procedure which check whether the number entered (as a nvarchar type) already exists or not. If it exists then the updation takes place, else an error is thrown out to the user. But am not able to create the procedure because as soon as I execute the command ERROR 102/156 SQL STATE 42000 comes up.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAWBUnique
(
    @AWB as nvarchar,
    @Internal as nvarchar
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    if((SELECT count(*) From Def_tab WHERE AWB=@AWB) == 0) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Def_tab SET AWB= @AWB
        where Internal=@Internal
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Already Exits'
    END
END
GO
```

FYI I use Microsoft SQL Server. How to clear this error and create the procedure?

Comment: `==` is not sql server syntax (also logically wrong)

Comment: Also, use IF EXISTS or IF NOT EXISTS as opposed to comparing counts like this.

Comment: @HoneyBadger how is the logic wrong ?  and thanks that solved the error

Comment: @ChrisBint Noted thanks !

Comment: @ObitoUchiha the logic is wrong because you're saying "if there are no rows that fulfills this condition, then update the rows that fulfill that condition".

Comment: @HoneyBadger yes ...if there are no entries with that number in AWB column then update the AWB column with that number ..thats what i meant..can it be done in a better way ?

Comment: @ObitoUchiha I'm sorry I misread. The logic is fine.

Comment: @HoneyBadger It's no problem but unfortunately my code doesn't seem to be working. Even though the compiler shows the query has been executed the AWB column doesn't show the updated value. and The print statement doesn't seem to be executing as well even if I give the repeated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally UPDATE and see if any changes happened

```
    UPDATE Def_tab 
    SET AWB = @AWB
    WHERE Internal = @Internal 
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Def_tab t WHERE t.AWB= @AWB)
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
        PRINT 'Already Exits'
```

Otherwise in a concurrent environment something may happen between

```
if((SELECT count(*) From Def_tab WHERE AWB=@AWB) == 0)
```

and

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE Def_tab SET AWB= @AWB
```

renderring the `if` check useless

Comment: @ObitoUchiha it can be `select null` as well. Here we don't care which data to select, just checking the existence of at least one row.

Comment: it shows two error in  the statement `AND NOT EXIST (SELECT null FROM Def_tab  WHERE AWB= @AWB)`
saying incorrect syntax near `select` and ')'

Tried it with 1 instead of null as well with same results

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `Def_Tab.AWB` to be unique.  If so, you should let the database enforce the data integrity.  Define a unique constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_def_tab_awb
    unique (awb);
```

No stored procedure is needed.

This will also check the value on `insert`.  And because the database is doing the check, you don't have to worry about whether or not the stored procedure is actually called when someone updates the table.